# How to move slider preview slow

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, slider

I need the slider preview to move by image but now it moves immediately to the end

I tried creating the preview slider with two buttons: left and right but when I pressed right it moved to the end, while I need it to move by image
Here is the link:
https://codepen.io/alexvambato/pen/yLGBxKK

```
<div class="img-container1" style="float:left; margin:10px;max-width: 530px">
<!-- Create slider. -->
<style>
/* See the styles on codepen.io */
</style>
<div id="thumbelina" style="padding:5px;overflow: hidden;">
<button class="btnToLeft" onclick="toMovel()"><</button>
    <ul id="thumbelina0" style="padding:0px; width:max-content; text-align:center;display: flex;margin-bottom: 0px;margin-left: 0px;">
    <li style="padding:5px;width: auto;height: 100px;display: block;"><img src="{{preview_image}}" style="margin-top: -5px;margin-left: -5px;" /></li>
      <li style="padding:5px;width: auto;height: 100px;display: block;"><img src="{{preview_image}}"  style="margin-top: -5px;margin-left: -5px;" /></li>
      <li style="padding:5px;width: auto;height: 100px;display: block;"><img src="{{preview_image}}"  style="margin-top: -5px;margin-left: -5px;" /></li>
      <li style="padding:5px;width: auto;height: 100px;display: block;"><img  style="margin-top: -5px;margin-left: -5px;" /></li>
      <li style="padding:5px;width: auto;height: 100px;display: block;"><img src="{{preview_image}}"  style="margin-top: -5px;margin-left: -5px;" /></li>
      <li style="padding:5px;width: auto;height: 100px;display: block;"><img src="{{preview_image}}" style="margin-top: -5px;margin-left: -5px;" /></li>
    </ul>
<button class="btnToRight" onclick="toMove()">></button>
</div>
</div>
<script>
function toMove() { 
var move = document.querySelector('#thumbelina0');
move.setAttribute('style', 'padding:0px; width:max-content; text-align:center;display: flex;margin-bottom: 0px;margin-left: -300px;')
}
function toMovel() { 
var move = document.querySelector('#thumbelina0');
move.setAttribute('style', 'padding:0px; width:max-content; text-align:center;display: flex;margin-bottom: 0px;margin-left: 0px;')
}
</script>
```

Comment: I mean, you set the fixed -300 left-margin value. How do you expect it to move to the image with a different width?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know how to do it otherwise so I ask for help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the width of the current image and increase/decrease the container's margin based on that value, not a fixed `-300px` or `0px`.

Didn't test it but this could work:

```js
let currentIndex = 0;

function toMove() { 
  const slider = document.querySelector('#thumbelina0');
  const element = document.querySelectorAll('li')[currentIndex];
  
  // there seems to be a hard-coded 10px in your style
  slider.style.marginLeft = parseInt(slider.style.marginLeft) - element.offsetWidth - 10 + 'px';
  
  currentIndex++;
}
```

For moving elements to left, it's a reverse action, so you just need to start adding the element width instead of subtracting it.

This is a quick-and-dirty solution but my suggestion is to use scroll offset instead of working with CSS like `margin-left`.

Answer (score 0):

To build a slider like that you would need to render the images & pictures in the same height and width.
For instance 100px and then every img should render the images as strengthen mode.
Once it's done you do need to write some code in javascript like this :

First of all, you need to define a variable that indicates slider position.

var pos = 0; //this should be global variable

and in movel and move functions you need to increase/decrease the value of `pos`.
Based on that you can set the margin value of the slider like this :

move.setAttribute('style', 'padding:0px; width:max-content; text-align:center;display: flex;margin-bottom: 0px;margin-left: '+pos*100+'px;')

Of course there should be limit of pos value as per image count and minus value.

Comment: Thank you very much, and how do I so that this function can be repeated several times

Comment: no, whenever click left or right buttons, you need to decrease/increase the pos value.